# Could somebody let me know in which case and which method should I use for upload / download blob?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

For azure blob storage sdk of c#, there're multi methods for download / upload blob.

Download methods: `DownloadText`, `DownloadToByteArray`, `DownloadToStream`, `DownloadToFile`.

Upload methods: `UploadText`, `UploadFromByteArray`, `UploadFromStream`, `UploadFromFile`.

How do I choose these methods? like when the file is large during download/upload, and would some methods cause encode issues etc.?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you uploading?

Comment: @CaiusJard like .txt files or some other files. And I want to understand the difference between these methods.

Comment: If you're uploading/downloading files use the xxxxFile methods

Comment: @CaiusJard, thank you. I knew that. I ask this question is more about the difference between these methods and in which case I should which one.

Comment: Tour queation os hard to answer because it's so obvious I'm struggling to understand why you're asking it. If you want a file or have a file use the file meThis. Sure you COULD read your file into memory then use the byte array, or open a stream to your file then use the stream.. but why would you? It's more code and more hassle. Your question actually seems to be more about when should you use a file, a stream or a byte array on a server, nothing to do with azure. You use what you have or you convert to fit within resource constraints. If your server has 512mb of memory don't try to read...

Comment: ...a 20gb file into a byte array before you upload the array to azure. Use a stream and read chunks of a few kb. If you're saving images in blobs and you want to download them, shift the hue or rotate by 90 degrees then write them to disk, download to a byte array, perform the manipulationthen write the bytes to disk.. I could go on, but hopefully you get my point that it totally depends on what you want to do with your data, and that is highly variable and you haven't told us so we can't really say other than "pick the most common sense method based on what you want to do or what you have"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You choose based on what you have or what you want; these things are here to make your life easy.

If you have/want a file, use the File methods (so you don't have to eg read your file into a byte array or attach a stream before uploading it, or so you can just download a file from the blob to your server)

If you have/want a stream, use the stream methods (imagine you want to send the blob data to a client, down a tcp socket - no point writing it to a file on your server then reading the file and sending it to the client, you should just open a stream from the blob and read from it and write to the rxpnsocket that goes to the client. This minimizes server resource use)

If you have/want an array, use the array methods (maybe you want to process it in memory some how)

See the docs for more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob?view=azure-dotnet